# Reference a prefab/asset in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to get a reference to a prefab in my assets folder via code.

[image]

[image]

I searched in the [documentation](https://docs.unity.com/) but couldn't find anything.

I expected to get something like:

```
GetComponent<>()
```

If someone knows a way to implement this via code please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: The `Resources` API is probably what you are looking for.  Why do you want to load the prefab from script instead of assigning the reference from the inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the pipe asset is a sprite so you would type:

```
public Sprite pipe;
```

And not:

```
public GameObject pipe;
```

GameObjects **are only assets can exist in the scene/level.** When you drag the sprite into your level, it will make a GameObject and add the correct components to display the sprite. Since you are trying to load the sprite from the folder, it is not a GameObject yet so the code you wrote will not work.

After you have made that little change. Saving the file should result in a little box in the inspector on the GameObject the script is on and that will allow you to select the sprite.

Comment: Ohh, I hadn't thought about this. Thank you very much.